# Citestyle in BibLaTeX with self-given style

Tags: biblatex

I'm using Biblatex (with biber exectuion) for my citing.

I'd like to set the citation style such, that a from me given letter+number combination is visible in the text, likes so:

```
This is the text in latex with a citation [AB123]. Another citation to this could be [BCA124].
```

Also the bibliography style should then show this same letter+number combination:

```
[ABC123]  Authorname, Title, etc...
[BCA124]  Authorname2, Title2, etc...
```

Since sorting is not easily done that way, it would be a nice extra feature, if the bibliography would be sorted by their upcoming in the `.bib` file.

I hope my question is clear, since I can't really put this into words.

Comment: Welcome. What package do you use for your bibliography?

Comment: I think I have the same problem and found somehow a solution using `natbib`. You can have a look at the documentation (https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) p.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged with `biblatex` here a biblatex option. The sorting is alphabetic, not by the bib.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{alphtest.bib}
@article{article1,
author={AuthorA},
title={title},
label = {ABC123}
}
@article{article2,
author={AuthorB},
title={title},
label = {BCA124}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{alphtest.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{article2}, \cite{article1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to exclude a possible date in the reference? For instance, I cite a book which is released 2017, then the citation mark gets [ABC12317].